# SharePoint 2013 Custom page layout template

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Currently i have a SharePoint site on its home page i have few web parts which i developed using Client object model(Java Script) i want the home page to be implemented as custom page layout. So when i create a new page with this page layout i will have all my web parts appearing on the page. I know we can do this with module and sever API model development, but i don't have access to write to server side code. It will be great if i can do with SharePoint Design or out-of-box?

I tried importing the web part and copying the code in Web Part file to Web Part zone in page layout but failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML page layout file and use design manager to convert it into an actual page layout.

For that you can use SharePoint designer or any other HTML editor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368(v=office.15).aspx